# Coffescript/JS with Rails, camelCase vs underscore naming style

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm working with a little team and we are writing a web system with ruby on rails. We use coffeescript, and we "adopted" the same style as ruby to write the coffeescript code, that means, with underscores instead of camelCase.

that's because we find so simple and consistent use underscore style in both, ruby and coffeescript, and all is easy to read for us.

But, I know the [JS naming convention](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp) says you should use camelCase, and my questions are:

Is It **really bad** that we follow our naming convention "underscore like ruby" to write coffeescript/javascript in our project? what kind of problems can this cause?

What are your recomendation? should we dont use at all underscore and change to camelCase to follow the convention for JS?

Comment: javascript naming conventions are not really relevant in coffeescript.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Except that all the "system level" stuff you access in CoffeeScript uses JavaScript conventions (such as `encodeURIComponent`, everything in `Array.prototype`, ...). Probably best (IMO) to use CoffeeScript conventions and the docs say things like `sayFortune = (fortune) ->` so it seems that JavaScript conventions are used.

Comment: @muistooshort: ah, it's my bad. I legitimately thought coffeescript's convention _is_ snake_case. That's how we wrote it as well :)

Comment: coffeescript really compiles to pure javascript at the end... therefore my doubt

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Conventions change? I remember snake case being the convention too (probably because of the Ruby influence) but now it seems to be camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I answer my own question reading this article:

https://github.com/polarmobile/coffeescript-style-guide

And the key sentece was:

**The official CoffeeScript convention is camelcase, because this simplifies interoperability with JavaScript.**